# Validation for numeric values with letters for exponential and hexadecimal notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing validation for my page using jQuery. For my ID text box, I want validation to accept numeric values only. When using `isNaN` or `isNumeric`, jQuery returns `false` and `true` respectively for values in the following formats:

- **12e3** - exponential notation
- **0x9** - hexadecimal notation

Aside from using isNaN and isNumeric, I can validate the values using regex by checking if the value contains a letter. Is there another way to check without using regex?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'isNumeric',
    function (value, element) {
        return !isNaN(value);
    },
    'Please check your number.'
);
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        numeric: {required: true, isNumeric: true},
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function validate(value) {
    return ( !isNaN(value) && value===Number(value).toString() );
}
```